# Integral behaviour?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I'm trying to find a standard integral, which shows itself up in general relativity (proper distance in Schwarzschild metric). For example in this [video](https://youtu.be/ZS22sw4NRDY?t=818). The integral is shown as

[image]
where $r_s< r$ and $r_s> 0$.
I've been trying to find this integral.

In Mathematica I can integrate the left hand side and get two different results, not of which match with the result shown before.

For

```
 In[1]:= \[Integral]1/Sqrt[1 - 1/r] \[DifferentialD]r   // Simplify
```

I get

```
Out[1]:=Sqrt[-1 + r] Sqrt[r] + ArcTanh[1/Sqrt[(-1 + r)/r]]
```

and for

```
In[2]:= \[Integral]1/Sqrt[1 - rs/r] \[DifferentialD]r   /. rs -> 1 // Simplify
```

I get

```
Out[2]:= Sqrt[(-1 + r)/r] r + ArcTanh[Sqrt[(-1 + r)/r]]
```

These two aren't the same, they both seem to be valid only for some interval. Also neither of these match the integral from the video (which can be derived by hand).
Plotting these

[image: Integral plot]

and further plotting the video integral

[image: Video integral]

Why does Mathematica behave in such a way and how do I go on about making Mathematica give me the result from the video?

Comment: (1) Both give correct antiderivatives. `In[1254]:= i1 = 1/Sqrt[1 - 1/r];
i2 = 1/Sqrt[1 - rs/r];
ii1 = Integrate[i1, r];
ii2 = Integrate[i2, r];
Simplify[D[ii1, r] - i1]
Simplify[D[ii2, r] - i2]

Out[1258]= 0

Out[1259]= 0`.

Comment: (2) Also neither looks to be quite the same as the integral shown at the top. And for that we also get a valid antiderivative. `In[1262]:= i3 = Sqrt[r/(r - rs)];
ii3 = Integrate[i3, r]
Simplify[D[ii3, r] - i3]

Out[1263]= (Sqrt[r/(r - rs)] (Sqrt[r] (r - rs) + Sqrt[r - rs] rs ArcTanh[Sqrt[r]/Sqrt[r - rs]]))/Sqrt[r]

Out[1264]= 0`

Comment: I agree that they are all valid antiderivatives, I wanted to know more about how mathematica chooses which antiderivative it will compute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope the following answers your question in 13.1 on Windows 10.

```
Integrate[Sqrt[r/(r - r[s])], r, Assumptions -> r[s] > 0 && r > r[s]];
FullSimplify[%, Assumptions -> r[s] > 0 && r > r[s]]
```

> `r^(3/2)/Sqrt[ r - r[s]] + (Log[Sqrt[r] + Sqrt[r - r[s]]] - Sqrt[r/(r - r[s])]) r[s]`

In fact, this answer is the same as the required one in view of

```
FullSimplify[r^(3/2)/Sqrt[r - r[s]] + (Log[Sqrt[r] + Sqrt[r - r[s]]] - Sqrt[r/(r - r[s])]) r[
s] - (Sqrt[r]*Sqrt[r - r[s]] + 
r[s]*Log[Sqrt[r] + Sqrt[r - r[s]]]), Assumptions -> r[s] > 0 && r > r[s]]
```

> `0`

Comment: Yes thank you, I've tried using Assumptions but must have given the wrong ones.